# Create .debs using Makefile in linux

Tags: linux, makefile, deb

How can we create .deb packages using Makefile in ubuntu.
Can anyone explain.am new in Makefile.

```
OSARCH := "linux/amd64 linux/386 windows/amd64 windows/386 darwin/amd64 darwin/386"
ENV = /usr/bin/env
VERSION=$(shell git describe --dirty --tags --always)

.SHELLFLAGS = -c # Run commands in a -c flag 
.SILENT: ; # no need for @
.ONESHELL: ; # recipes execute in same shell
.NOTPARALLEL: ; # wait for this target to finish
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES: ; # send all vars to shell

.PHONY: all # All targets are accessible for user
.DEFAULT: help # Running Make will run the help target

help: ## Show Help
        @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'

dep: ## Get build dependencies
        go get -v -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep

ensure: ## update dependencies
        dep ensure

build: ## Build the app
        for gomodule in  $$(go list ./... | grep -vE 'x1|x2|x3|x4|x5|myself|rfc****') ; do
                go build -gcflags "-N -l" -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION) -s -w"  -o bin/$$(basename $$gomodule).s $$gomodule
                upx --force -qq -o bin/$$(basename $$gomodule) bin/$$(basename $$gomodule).s > /dev/null
        done

test: ## Launch tests
        go test -v ./...

clean: ## Launch clean
        go clean ./...
        rm -rf bin

install: ## Launch install
        go install -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION)" $$(go list ./... | grep -v test)

test-cover: ## Launch tests coverage and send it to coverall
        $(ENV) ./scripts/test-coverage.sh
```

How to add lines to this makefile to create .deb packages after using the command `sudo make`

Comment: You put the command to create the Debian package into the Makefile. That's it. Both make and Debian packaging are well documented. Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: I want to create debian packaging from this same makefile.now, in  this makefile only binaries are created. how can I achieve it.can please help me

Answer (score 1):

To create a Debian package in general, you need to have two directory trees: one with the actual files you want to package, and one with the control information for the package. You'll need a tree somewhat like this one:

```
+ DEBIAN
| + control
+ files
  + bin
  | + myapp
  + etc
  | + myapp.ini
  ...
```

The file `control` is a text file with some mandatory fields as documented in [`man dpkg-control`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/deb-control).

To create a Debian package, refer to [`man dpkg-deb`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg-deb). The command line to do it looks like this

```
dpkg-deb --build files my-package_<version>_<arch>.deb
```

Reading your `Makefile`, it looks as if you created your binaries in a `bin` right below the project root. So you would either need to create them somewhere else or copy them into a tree for package creation.

Assuming all your files (DEBIAN and installation) reside in a directory `package`, these are the lines you would need to put into your `Makefile`:

```
package: <artifacts you want to package>
    dpkg-deb --build package my-package_<version>_<arch>.deb
```

A variable to contain the version will make things easier. (Hint: there's also version information in the `control` file and they should not contradict each other. You can set one from the other with a line of script.) The target architecture is only known to you.

Note that above is a *very minimal* example. There's lots of optional and highly useful functionality you can leverage.
For further reading, refer to the Debian docs on [Control files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) and [Package maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#).

It might also be worthwhile to read the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/). Notably, your `Makefile` does not define any prerequisites for the targets (which is a prime motivation for using `make` in the first place) and `.PHONY: all` does not do what the comment says. In fact, it does nothing because there's no target named `all`.

Start with the manual's [introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) and move on until you get an impression how `Makefile`s work. Then consider doing an overhaul of your `Makefile` with your newly gained knowledge. It's really well-documented and straightforward.

Comment: `package: <artifacts you want to package>
    dpkg-deb --build package my-package_<version>_<arch>.deb`
what we have to give as <artifacts you want to package>

Comment: How can I add one more makefile to existing above makefile. does the variables declared in first makefile pass to second makefile. very thankfull for your help.

Comment: The [prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction) go there. That would be the files you want to package. You can leave it blank as you did with every rule in your Makefile but then you're only using half of `make`'s power. Consider doing a full overhaul of your Makefile to get it straight but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: cab you please explain me what is prerequisites and for what we use prerequistes in makefile. am newbie in this.please explain me what is target and what is it's use?

Comment: You can [include](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) other Makefiles but that's a whole new question. You've got to read the docs yourself. Read the [intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction), it does a much better job explaining Makefiles than I ever could.